# Antonym of coercive

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for an antonym of the word coercive, i.e., a leader who gets something done merely by asking instead of forcing someone to do something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Persuasive? (I realize that's not exactly what you're asking for, but it's a necessary quality.)

Comment: I agree it is a necessary quality. I'm hoping for a one word adjective. Maybe there isn't one.

Comment: It's not exactly in widespread use, but to me the "antonym" of a *coercive* leader would be an *inductive* leader. I don't really see how *asking/forcing* can be seen as "opposites" in the context of how a "leader" acts. If your boss says *"Jump!"*, you don't say *"Are you asking me, or telling me?"* - you ask *"How high?"*

Comment: Inductive is almost there.

Comment: charismatic?  But `coercive` doesn't mean forceful - it means coercive.

Comment: How about "non-coercive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best antonym depends on which connotations of *coercive* you want to negate. A leader who motivates people to act instead of ordering them could be *persuasive, charismatic,* or *inspiring.* A leader who values input instead of ignoring it could be *democratic* or *considerate.*

Comment: I think this answer best describes what I'm trying to define. However, I don't think there is a single word for it.

Answer (score 4):

Try **conducive**

> Tending to produce; conducing; contributive; helpful; favorable
>   ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conducive))
>
> Tending to contribute to, encourage, or bring about some result. ([AskDefine.com](http://conducive.askdefine.com/))

Examples of its use are at these links:

[How To Maintain A Conducive Classroom Environment.](http://ask.reference.com/web?q=How%20To%20Maintain%20A%20Conducive%20Classroom%20Environment?&o=100100)

[How to create a conducive workspace.](http://ask.reference.com/web?q=How%20To%20Create%20A%20Conducive%20Work%20Space?&o=100100)

Comment: In my experience, *conducive* isn't an adjective used to describe people, but rather environments, situations, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Passive** perhaps. There is not likely to be a direct equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

What about ***coax***?

It doesn't imply pushiness or force.